# Specify code to run before any Jest setup happens

Tags: javascript, jestjs

The tl;dr is:

1) How can I have Jest use the native `require` function to load all modules in my tests anywhere.

2) Where / how would I go about modifying (ie replacing with the esm loader) https://github.com/standard-things/esm the require function in one place, before any tests run, so all tests will use the modified require.

---

I'd like to use the [esm-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@std/esm) with my Jest test files.  In order to do so, I need to patch the require function globally, before any test code runs, with something like

`require = require("@std/esm")(module, { esm: "js", cjs: true });`

How do I tell Jest to execute that code before anything else is touched or requested?

I tried pointing both `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` and an `setupFiles` array entry to a file with that in it, but neither worked (though I did confirm that both ran).

Alternatively, I'm firing off these tests with an npm script

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest"
}
```

Is there some CLI magic whereby I can just load a module *and then* run `jest`?

---

Edit - the `testEnvironment` and `resolver` options make me wonder if this is ever even using the actual Node `require` function to load modules, or instead using its own module loader.  If so I wonder if this is even possible.

Comment: [`transform`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string)?

Comment: @OrB - thanks, but no, sadly.  What I need is lower-level.  U want to replace the root Node require loader with a shimmed one that supports ES6.  But given my edit I'm not even certain Node is using the root Node resolver, so this may not even be possible

Comment: From your npm script usage, the [jest-cli](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/77744a24816d0978b6c478987426c36d615864bd/packages/jest-cli/bin/jest.js) should be the first thing that runs.  You could try editing this file locally, patching the require function with `require("@std/esm")`, before `require('../build/cli').run();`. If this works, you can at least confirm that your idea is sound.

Comment: @BrandonBoone good idea - I did that, and still no change (and I definitely confirmed I had the right file).  It seems Jest simply does not use Node's `require` to load modules inside the tests (which makes sense given their module mocking abilities.)

Comment: Perhaps. Jest does have 2 packages [jest-resolve-dependencies](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/jest-resolve-dependencies) and [jest-resolve](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/jest-resolve) which appear to be working together to resolve module paths. I does look like you can override it through through [configuration](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#resolver-string)

Comment: This may also be relevant: "By default, @std/esm only processes files of packages that opt-in with a @std/esm options object or @std/esm as a dependency, dev dependency, or peer dependency in their package.json".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So this one was a bit tough to get working. The solution is quite simple but it took me a while to get it working. The problem is that whenever you use any module in jest

- Setup Files
- Setup Framework Files
- Test Files
- Module files

They are all loaded in below way

> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){**/*Module code inside*/**
>   }});

If you have a look at `node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:495:510`

```
const dirname = (_path || _load_path()).default.dirname(filename);
localModule.children = [];
localModule.parent = mockParentModule;
localModule.paths = this._resolver.getModulePaths(dirname);
localModule.require = this._createRequireImplementation(filename, options);

const transformedFile = this._scriptTransformer.transform(
filename,
{
  collectCoverage: this._coverageOptions.collectCoverage,
  collectCoverageFrom: this._coverageOptions.collectCoverageFrom,
  collectCoverageOnlyFrom: this._coverageOptions.collectCoverageOnlyFrom,
  isInternalModule,
  mapCoverage: this._coverageOptions.mapCoverage },

this._cacheFS[filename]);
```

`this._createRequireImplementation(filename, options);` gives every module a custom require object. So you as such don't get the native require function at all, anywhere. Once jest has started every module loaded from then on will have jest's custom `require` function.

When we load a module, the `requireModule` methods from the `jest-runtime` gets called. Below is an excerpt from the same

```
  moduleRegistry[modulePath] = localModule;
  if ((_path || _load_path()).default.extname(modulePath) === '.json') {
    localModule.exports = this._environment.global.JSON.parse(
    (0, (_stripBom || _load_stripBom()).default)((_gracefulFs || _load_gracefulFs()).default.readFileSync(modulePath, 'utf8')));

  } else if ((_path || _load_path()).default.extname(modulePath) === '.node') {
    // $FlowFixMe
    localModule.exports = require(modulePath);
  } else {
    this._execModule(localModule, options);
  }
```

As you can see if the extension of the file is `.node` it loads the module directly, else it calls the `_execModule`. This function is the same code that I posted earlier which does the code transformation

```
const isInternalModule = !!(options && options.isInternalModule);
const filename = localModule.filename;
const lastExecutingModulePath = this._currentlyExecutingModulePath;
this._currentlyExecutingModulePath = filename;
const origCurrExecutingManualMock = this._isCurrentlyExecutingManualMock;
this._isCurrentlyExecutingManualMock = filename;

const dirname = (_path || _load_path()).default.dirname(filename);
localModule.children = [];
localModule.parent = mockParentModule;
localModule.paths = this._resolver.getModulePaths(dirname);
localModule.require = this._createRequireImplementation(filename, options);
```

Now when we want to modify `require` function for our test, we need `_execModule` to export our code directly. So the code should be similar to loading of a `.node` modules

```
  } else if ((_path || _load_path()).default.extname(modulePath) === '.mjs') {
    // $FlowFixMe
    require = require("@std/esm")(localModule);
    localModule.exports = require(modulePath);
  } else {
```

But doing that would mean patching the code, which we want to avoid. So what we do instead is avoid using the jest command directly, and create our own `jestload.js` and running that. The code for loading jest is simple

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014-present, Facebook, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

cli = require('jest/bin/jest');
```

Now we want to modify the `_execModule` before the cli loads. So we add below code

```
const jestRuntime = require("jest-runtime");
oldexecModule = jestRuntime.prototype._execModule;

jestRuntime.prototype._execModule = function (localModule, options) {
    if (localModule.id.indexOf(".mjs") > 0) {
        localModule.exports = require("@std/esm")(localModule)(localModule.id);
        return localModule;
    }
    return oldexecModule.apply(this, [localModule, options]);
};

cli = require('jest/bin/jest');
```

Now time for a test

```
//__test__/sum.test.js
sum = require('../sum.mjs').sum;


test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});


test('adds 2 + 3 to equal 5', () => {
  expect(sum(3, 2)).toBe(5);
});
```

And a `sum.mjs` file

```
export function sum (x, y) { return x + y }
```

Now we run the test

[image: Jest Test]

The solution is available on below repo

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/jest-overriding-require-function-stackoverflow

You can clone and test the solution by running `npm test`.

Comment: I get `Unexpected token export` when I attempt to [run the test from the repo](https://github.com/tarunlalwani/jest-overriding-require-function-stackoverflow/issues/1) with node v10.5.0.

Comment: Can you try with Node 8 LTS version? That is what it was tested with

Answer (score 4):

`setupFiles` worked for me. Add this in package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["./my_file.js"]
  },
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array

Comment: What's the content of `my_file.js`?

Comment: anything that you want to run before your jest files. In my case it's adding a pollyfill: import 'raf/polyfill';

Comment: Right, but what exactly needs to be in that file to make Jest load ES modules using a modified `require`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it has two down votes! Also i think the answer could have a little more info from de official website like "setupFiles is a list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment.". I'll try this, seems to be exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I tried using `node -r @std/esm run.js` where run.js is just a script that calls jest, but it does not work and crashes here : https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-runtime/src/script_transformer.js#L305.

From what I understand from this line means that it is not possible because jest compiles the module using the native `vm` module. The above lines (290):

```
  if (willTransform) {
    const transformedSource = this.transformSource(
    filename,
    content,
    instrument,
    !!(options && options.mapCoverage));


    wrappedCode = wrap(transformedSource.code);
    sourceMapPath = transformedSource.sourceMapPath;
  } else {
```

is the code called when you are specifying transforms in your jest config.

Conclusion : until esm are supported ( and they will be under the `.mjs` extension ) you cannot import es modules in jest **without** specifying a transform. You could try to monkey patch `vm` but I would really advise against this option.

Specifying a jest transform is really not that hard, and for es modules it's really as simple as using `babel-jest` with the right babel config :

Below a package.json with minimal settings

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
        "jest": "^21.2.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "testMatch": [
            "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
            "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
        },
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testURL": "http://localhost",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json"
        ]
    },
    "babel": {
        "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
}
```