# express body-parser utf-8 error in test

Tags: node.js, express, postman, jestjs, body-parser

Super stumped by this. I have some server code that for some reason throws a UTF-8 error in my tests but works fine when running the server normally:

code:

```
export default ({ projectId = PROJECT_ID, esHost = ES_HOST } = {}) => {
  let app = express();
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

  let http = Server(app);
  let io = socketIO(http);

  let server = {
    app,
    io,
    http,
    status: 'off',
    listen(
      port = PORT,
      cb = () => {
        rainbow(`⚡️ Listening on port ${port} ⚡️`);
      },
    ) {
      this.http.listen(port, () => {
        main({ io, app, projectId, esHost, port });
        this.status = 'on';
        cb();
      });
    },
    close(cb = () => {}) {
      if (this.http) {
        this.http.close(() => {
          this.status = 'off';
          cb();
        });
      } else {
        throw '❗️ cannot close server that has not been started ❗️';
      }
    },
  };

  return server;
};
```

usage (exactly the same, but in jest test body-parser isn't working properly):

```
import createServer from '../server'

let server = createServer()
server.listen(5050);
```

I'm using postman, post response outside of test:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": "test",
            "active": true,
            "timestamp": "2018-02-25T21:33:08.006Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "TEST-PROJECT",
            "active": true,
            "timestamp": "2018-03-05T21:34:34.604Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "asd",
            "active": true,
            "timestamp": "2018-03-06T23:29:55.348Z"
        }
    ],
    "total": 3
}
```

unexpected post response inside jest test server:

Error

```
UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported charset "UTF-8"
    at /Users/awilmer/Projects/arranger/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:83:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/awilmer/Projects/arranger/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: installed everything, tests all pass, did you try to delete node_modules, `npm cache clean` and fresh install everything again?

Comment: Which OS are you using to test this?

Comment: I'm running a osx 10.12.6..nodejs 8.4. I will try a completely fresh install on another machine

Comment: @azium, I am able to reproduce your issue, the issue is jest only here. It won't happen in other frameworks. I am looking for possible solutions now

Comment: @azium, posted the solution. Have a look

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce the issue and find the source of the issue and the workaround to make it work. The issue is caused by `jest` framework.

Before you jump on reading the rest of the thread, I would suggest you read another Jest thread I answer long back. This would help get some context internals about the `require` method in `jest`

[Specify code to run before any Jest setup happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433678/specify-code-to-run-before-any-jest-setup-happens/46575077#46575077)

**Cause**

The issue happens only in test and not in production. This is because of `jest` require method.

When you run your tests, it starts a express server, which calls the `node_modules/raw-body/index.js` as shown in below image

[image: ICONV lite]

As you can see the `encodings` is `null`. This is because the `iconv-lite` module does a lazy loading of `encodings`. The encodings are only loaded when `getCodec` method gets executed.

Now when your test has fired the API, the server needs to read the body so the `getCodec` gets called

[image: Lazy Loading]

This then goes through the `jest-runtime/build/index.js` custom `require` method (which is overloaded if you read the previous link).

[image: Jest execModule]

The `execModule` has a check for `this._environment.global`, which is blank in this case and hence a `null` value is returned and the module never gets executed

[image: No global]

Now when you look at the exports of the `encodings` module, it just is a blank object

[image: No exports]

So the issue is purely a `jest`. A feature jest lacks or a bug mostly?

**Related Issues**

Related issues have already been discussed on below threads

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2605

https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/N3.js/issues/120

https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/489#issuecomment-313374683

https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/issues/118

https://github.com/Jason-Rev/vscode-spell-checker/issues/159

**Fix**

The fix to the problem is that we load the module during our test itself and force a early loading instead of lazy loading. This can be done by adding a line to your `index.test.js` at the top

```
import encodings from '../../node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings';
import createServer from '@arranger/server';
```

After the change all the test pass, though you have a error in the url of the test so you get `Cannot POST /`

[image: Working Test]

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Best karma I've ever spent.

Comment: I have been trying to create a small reproducible test for the same and figure out whats wrong. But seems this is an edge case that you have unearthed. The express and body parser work fine even across project with lazy loading. You should open a issue with Jest and give them this repo and the SO link to reproduce and fix the issue

Comment: Great answer. I just added `require('iconv-lite/encodings');` to the top of my file and it magically works.

Comment: hi there, after importing '../../node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings', where to use assigned variable then

Comment: You don't need to use it, just importing does the job

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a slightly different solution inspired from @Tarun Lalwani

Add the following lines at the top of your test file.

```
const encodings = require('./node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings');                                                                                                                                                                       
const iconvLite = require('./node_modules/iconv-lite/lib');                                                                                                                                                                             
iconvLite.getCodec('UTF-8');
```

Comment: What is your version of iconvlite ? I only see utf-7 and utf-16 version in iconvlite

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours trying to figure out why Jest would report a 415 error code when testing the Node.js server. Node.js is configured to use `app.use(bodyParser.json(...));` on our system, too. That didn't solve the issue.

## Solution

When using `res.status(...)`, you MUST either chain on `.json()` or use `res.json()`, too. That means if you respond with a 500 error or otherwise and you don't return any JSON data, you still need to use `res.json()`. No idea why, as that defeats the whole purpose of `app.use(bodyParser.json(...));` in the first place.

## Example

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  // ...
  res.status(500).json();
  // ...
});
```